# Custom Checkbox and Label Overlapping in HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm Trying to make an Review Form in HTML, and I created this Custom Checkbox everything is working fine, it changes color when I hover mouse over it, but label text is overlapping over Checkbox, I tried to find it but still no clue.
Here is code.

```css
/* checkbox css starts here */

.exp {
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.exp>label {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: "Lucida Console";
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: rgb(128, 204, 255);
  border: 3px solid rgb(32, 33, 37);
}

.exp>input {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.exp>label::after {
  opacity: 0.2;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 6px;
  left: 5px;
  border: 3px solid rgb(5, 16, 51);
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.exp>label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.exp>input:checked~label::after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="exp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="fun" id="fun" />
  <label for="fun">Fun</label>
</div>
<div class="exp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="entertaining" id="entertaining" />
  <label for="entertaining">Entertaining</label>
</div>
<div class="exp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="challanging" id="challanging" />
  <label for="challanging">Challanging</label>
</div>
<div class="exp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="wholesome" id="wholesome" />
  <label for="wholesome">Wholesome</label>
</div>
<div class="exp">
  <input type="checkbox" name="other" id="other" />
  <label for="other">Other</label>
</div>
```

**O/P**:
[Overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No85h.png)

Please Help!

Comment: I have answered your query below. Please review if it works fine for you and let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have styled the `<label>` as a checkbox. The text is inside the `<label>` that visually looks like a checkbox.

You can use `text-indent` to move the text to the right like shown below

```css
.exp{
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}
.exp > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    text-indent: 30px;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgb(128, 204, 255);
    border: 3px solid rgb(32, 33, 37);
}
.exp > input {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.exp > label::after{
    opacity: 0.2;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(5, 16, 51);
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.exp > label:hover::after{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.exp > input:checked ~ label::after{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="fun" id="fun" />
                <label for="fun">Fun</label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="entertaining" id="entertaining" />
                <label for="entertaining">Entertaining</label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="challanging" id="challanging" />
                <label for="challanging">Challanging</label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="wholesome" id="wholesome" />
                <label for="wholesome">Wholesome</label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="other" id="other" />
                <label for="other">Other</label>
           </div>
```

Comment: Good answer! Didn't know about the `text-indent` property

Comment: Yup. Good answer !

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your checkbox labels inside a `<span>` tag.

Here's a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0jwcrxzm/

```
   <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="fun" id="fun" />
                <label for="fun"><span class="label-span">Fun</span></label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="entertaining" id="entertaining" />
                <label for="entertaining"><span class="label-span">Entertaining</span></label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="challanging" id="challanging" />
                <label for="challanging"><span class="label-span">Challanging</span></label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="wholesome" id="wholesome" />
                <label for="wholesome"><span class="label-span">Wholesome</span></label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="other" id="other" />
                <label for="other"><span class="label-span">Other</span></label>
           </div>

/* checkbox css starts here */
.exp{
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}
.exp > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgb(128, 204, 255);
    border: 3px solid rgb(32, 33, 37);
}
.exp > input {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.exp > label::after{
    opacity: 0.2;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(5, 16, 51);
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.exp > label:hover::after{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.exp > input:checked ~ label::after{
    opacity: 1;
}

.label-span {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please upvote on the answer that you found helpful? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the label text with a span and give it a padding

See code below

```css
/* checkbox css starts here */
.exp{
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}
.exp > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgb(128, 204, 255);
    border: 3px solid rgb(32, 33, 37);
}
.exp > input {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.exp > label::after{
    opacity: 0.2;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 6px;
    left: 5px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(5, 16, 51);
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.exp > label:hover::after{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.exp > input:checked ~ label::after{
    opacity: 1;
}

.label-text {
  padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="exp">
    <input type="checkbox" name="fun" id="fun" />
    <span class="cbox"></span>
    <label for="fun">
       <span class="label-text">Fun</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is What I did after few trys ,I made an separate span for custom checkbox and then it was easy to separate label and that custom checkbox.

**Html**

```
<div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="fun" id="fun" />
                <span class="cbox"></span>
                <label for="fun">Fun</label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="entertaining" id="entertaining" />
                <span class="cbox"></span>
                <label for="entertaining">Entertaining</label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="challanging" id="challanging" />
                <span class="cbox"></span>
                <label for="challanging">Challanging</label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="wholesome" id="wholesome" />
                <span class="cbox"></span>
                <label for="wholesome">Wholesome</label>
           </div>
           <div class="exp">
                <input type="checkbox" name="other" id="other" />
                <span class="cbox"></span>
                <label for="other">Other</label>
           </div>
```

**Css**

```
/* checkbox css starts here */
.exp{
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    
}
.exp > label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin: -10px 2em;
    font-family: "Lucida Console";
}
.cbox{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: -10px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: rgb(128, 204, 255);
    border: 3px solid rgb(32, 33, 37);
}
.exp > input {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.exp > .cbox::after{
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 4px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 6px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.exp:hover .cbox::after {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.exp > input:checked ~ .cbox::after{
    opacity: 1;
}
```